# Find missing point of Isosceles triangle by knowing all sides and angles in 3D

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

I have some problems finding the missing point of the isosceles triangle. I have known 2 points P(2,6,1) and Q(-1,3,5) and all sides and all angles of it. But when I'm trying to find another point O(x,y,z) by using its distance to each known point, I can get the 3 to 4 equations but those equations when subtracting it, it showed 0 = 0 in which infinite answer.
Is there any way to solve this problem?
Thank you

Comment: The plane that perpendicularly bisects PQ contains the set of points such that OPQ is an isosceles triangle.

Comment: "I have known $2$ points $P(2,6,1)$ and $Q(-1,3,5)$ and all sides and all angles of it." maybe it would be useful to include this information into the question too (sides lengths). @SamannLong

Comment: For OP = OQ = 3 and PQ = 5.83095189485, angel of POQ = 152.733955549267 degree and angel OPQ = OQP = 13.6330222253664 degree

Comment: Then you will have a specific circle on that plane that contains the set of points where $O$ could potentially be.

Comment: So there is no way that we can find a specific answer of O?

Comment: If you find a specific point, it will not be the only correct answer.  And so, unless there is more to the question, I would suspect that the question might be asking for a parametric solution.